# Calculating standard deviation of a sample

Tags: python, resampling, standard-deviation, variance, population

This looks a bit confusing. When you need to calculate the std, you can easily use `np.std()`. And Std is square root of variance. However, when we calculate variance of a sample, we divide it by `n-1`. So if we use `np.std()` this shouldn't give us a correct output.

Is there another way to calculate standard deviation of a sample or do we need to calculate it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the denominator degrees of freedom when you use `np.std()`. Just use the `ddof` parameter:

```
np.std(x, ddof=1)
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it same for pandas?

Comment: in this doc of pandas, it states that pandas use 1 as default - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html

Comment: It seems they use a different default. numpy defaults to 0, whereas pandas defaults to 1

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument **ddof** while executing **np.std()**

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

vsum=0
for x in a:
    vsum=vsum + (x - np.mean(a))**2

variance=vsum / (len(a) - 1)
print("Variance is {} and Actual STD Dev is {} ".format(variance,np.sqrt(variance)))
print("np.std is {} and np.std with parameter is {} ".format(np.std(a),np.std(a,ddof=1)))
```

What ddof=1 does is makes numpy use the delta degrees of freedom to 1

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it same for pandas?